# Java and SQL: Receive partial ResultSet and use SwingWorker's publish() to show incoming results

Tags: java, sql, resultset, swingworker

I have a program which issues SQL queries to return long lists of objects, I want to make the GUI responsive and receiving parts of SQL results in chunks would make it possible to update the GUI as soon as some data from the query arrives.

Is there some way to do it? Right now the GUI shows nothing until the query has returned the whole Resultset, so a SwingWorker publish() method is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the SQl query. E.g. in MySQL you can add LIMIT 10,20 to retrieve only part of select results

```
[LIMIT [offset,] rows | rows OFFSET offset]
```

UPDATE you can add count to the same query and get the count in the first row to avoid additional DB call

```
select * from (select count(*) as count, 0 as id from users
               union all
               select 0 as count, id from users limit 0,10) full
ORDER BY count desc
limit 0,11;
```

Comment: I suspected that was the only way, however to do a LIMIT I should first query for the number of records, which is another query I wanted to avoid. Plus doing several queries with LIMIT specified means opening a connection each time, which I wanted to avoid.